# Why does `@file:Suppress("ALL")` not work for everything?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

I generate code and I don't care about the warnings, this is the first line of the file:

`@file:Suppress("ALL")`

I still do get warnings though:

[image]

How do I suppress EVERYTHING? I am having a hard time to see a list of all constants of `Suppress`, so if anybody can add that I would be happy. The warnings pop up also in the `Build Output` tab.

Comment: Are you using any plugins like SonarLint?

Comment: @dan1st I only use Detekt, I changed my line to `@file:Suppress("ALL", "detekt:all", "all")` but it still shows the same warnings.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think that if you mark the directory as "Generated sources root", it will not apply any inspections.

Comment: should it not be `@file:Suppress("warnings")` or `@file:Suppress("SENSELESS_COMPARISON")` instead?

Comment: @user2340612 That one is just an example of some warning that gets past when you suppress "All". It's not about "senseless comparison" - it's about some string that will encompass every single warning.

Comment: gotcha. I think `@Suppress("all")` works only with Detekt, while `@Suppress("warnings")` should allow suppressing Kotlin compiler's warnings

Comment: @user2340612 that actually worked, you can place it as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not documented – or anyway I couldn't find any documentation – so it's surprisingly hard to find an answer but from what I observed/found:

- `@Suppress("all")` is defined by Detekt: https://detekt.dev/docs/introduction/suppressing-rules/
- The Kotlin compiler gives you an indication of the value you should use if you want to suppress a specific warning (e.g., `@Suppress("KotlinConstantConditions")`)
- Apparently, `@Suppress("warnings")` disables all warnings, but couldn't find any documentation on this